# Little complex MYSQL join

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to add categories param to this function :

```
    public function get_prog_channel($chaine_id = NULL, $nb = NULL, $debut = NULL) {
    $q = $this->db->select('*');
    $q->from($this->table_prog);
    if($nb !==NULL || $debut !== NULL){
    $q->LIMIT($nb, $debut);}

    if ($chaine_id !== NULL) {
        $q->where('channel_id', $chaine_id);
         $q->join($this->table_emission, 'programs.id=emissions.id');

                  return $q ->get()
                            ->result();
    } else {
        return $q->get()
                  ->result();

    }


}
```

here is my tables :

- programs(id,title,emission_id...)
- emissions(id,....,channel_id) categorie(id,...)
- rel_emission_categories(category_id,emission_id)

how can i do that plz ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify, but that looks like PHP using the CodeIgniter Framework. If so, modify the following to suit your needs.

```
$query="SELECT *
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 on table1.col=table2.col
WHERE table1.whatever=? AND table1.hello=?
LIMIT 1";
$params=array();
$params[]='whatever';
$params[]='world';


$result=$this->db->query($query,$params);
$result=$result->result_array();
print_r($result);
```